# Regex without * operator

Tags: regex

Here is my input text:

```
 String input = "Current year is: 2014";
```

I just want to find the first alphabetic word(without numbers) using POSIX character classes. Following regex works and finds 'Current'

```
String pattern = "\\p{Alpha}*"; //Current
```

But I am not allowed to use * operator. Therefore, my question, how can I get the same result without using * ?

Comment: *But I am not allowed to use * operator* Why?

Comment: I am making some course slides and the operators +, *, ? etc come later, after this example

Comment: Then show it later? The correct way to do this is by using the `*` quantifier... An alternative would be to use `{0,}` as a quantifier, but if this is a course, I would recommend going through all the quantifiers at the same time.

Comment: I think you should be pick an example that doesn't require extracting specific classes until you have introduced the iteration operators.

Comment: what is `\\p` represents in your pattern? What lang is this? Is this Java?

Comment: I strongly recommend introducing the Kleene closure before character classes. The Kleene closure is a fundamental part of regexp. The `+` operator can be emulated using the Kleene closure (`a+` = `aa*`) so that can be introduced later. The core of regexp is character literal, the `any` match (`.`) the Kleene closure (`*`) and alternation (`|`). Everything else are just extensions for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Use a + :

```
String pattern = "\\p{Alpha}+";
```

It's pretty much the same, only "zero" occurencies aren't allowed.

Comment: OP said in a comment `+` is not allowed, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{n,}` quantifier, e.g.:

```
String pattern = "\\p{L}{0,}";
```

Comment: I didn't know you could omit the maximum! Thanks for the top tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use *, which means 0 or more, what about `{0,}` ?